# One' s Complement of a number

Tags: c

suppose i have a variable

int a=512

Now when i apply ~a which means one's complement in c.How i am getting -513 as the output.

int is minimum 16 bits in size and binary equivalent of 512 is

0000 0010 0000 0000 And now when you do its one's complement it becomes

1111 1101 1111 1111. Now could someone tell me why the output is -513.

Can I now Hope that guys in this forum understood my question.

Comment: The operator '~' is called "bitwise negation". "One's complement" is just a way of representing signed numbers, but there are others like the widespread "two's complement". In case of "One's complement" bitwise negation acts like arithmetic negation, which in C is performed by the unary '-' operator (there's also a binary '-'). However they have completely different meaning. '~' is just toggling each bit, ignoring any semantics of the underlying type. '-' is aware of the type's semantics.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Negative numbers are often represented as [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), which is why it is interpreted the way it is.

Assuming `int` is 16-bit, you will have the bitpattern `1111 1101 1111 1111`. Since the top-most bit is set, the number is negative. To convert to decimal, according to the rules for two's complement, the number is first bitwise-inverted. This brings back your 512. Then one is added, which gives 513. And since the number was negative, we get -513.

Comment: couldn't have put it better myself.